# Save simple Ruby script and its output in one file

Tags: ruby, jupyter-notebook, irb, pry

I want to save simple Ruby script and its output in one file. 
I know jupyter-notebook is a good tool for that. Ruby scripts can be executed with jupyter by using iruby. But I do not want to use iruby. Because iruby is unstable and jupyter is overengineered for me.

So I am looking for an easy way.

hello.rb

```
puts "hello world"
2 + 3
```

execute some nice command

```
irbliketool hello.rb > output.txt
```

output.txt will look like this...

```
irb > puts "hello world"
hello world
=> nil

irb > 2+3
=> 5
```

Are there good ideas?

Comment: `cat hello.rb | irb > out.txt`

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a file to `irb`.

```
irb hello.rb > output.txt
```

Not quite the same output but you can also do this:

```
cat hello.rb | irb > out.txt
```